# Laravel auth using GET method

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

In my laravel project, i use zizaco/entrust for role base authentication. I have two role admin and user. Now i want user can loginin two process. One process to normal login system in laravel (It's working well) and another process to use get method like
    http://myproject/login?username=username&password=password
when user set this url, then call login route where email & password get from url's username & password and after matching data login user successfully.
Now i have to question that how can i handle 2nd process to login from user.
Any technique can i follow?

Comment: You should not use `GET` requests for login. This will expose the user's details in their browser history, etc.

Comment: What reason do you have for needing to use a `GET` request?

Comment: It's client requirement.

Comment: I have same question that you question me

Comment: You should inform them that it's not secure. PII (usernames, passwords) will be stored in server logs, browsers, etc. This is illegal under GDPR as well

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147188/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-get-method-as-login-username-password-for-administrato

Comment: Client use the project only for their inhouse system & this process will combined with another project. So he want this process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please note: If possible, you should avoid using `GET` requests to login. PII (usernames, passwords) will be stored in server logs, browsers, etc.

See: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147188/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-get-method-as-login-username-password-for-administrato

Assuming you are using the default laravel auth, you can just create a `GET` method for the `login` method on the `LoginController`:

```php
Route::get('login-insecure', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login.insecure');
```

This means you can login using a url such as:

> https://myproject,com/login-insecure?username=username&password=password

You should definitely use `HTTPS` as well if you go down this route, as otherwise anyone on the network could intercept usernames & passwords.